# Efficient representation of class properties at runtime

Tags: c, compiler-construction, interpreter, vm-implementation

I am developing a class based language and virtual machine (using C). Language is dynamically typed and I am designing how a class must be represented at runtime.

Basically a syntax like:

```
class Point {
      var x;
      var y;
}
```

is represented at runtime by a struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int        numfields;
    const char *name;
    class_t    *super;
    void       *methods[];
} class_t;
```

The only information needed about class properties are the number of properties (var) and their positions. So the compiler can know that an instance of class Point will have property x at position 0 and property y at position 1.

An instance will be simply represented by a struct like:

```
typedef struct {
    class_t class;
    value   fields[];
} instance_t;
```

Everything works fine until I tried to implement loading of external code by an already compiled application. If that external code contains a class ColorPoint (subclass of Point) defined as:

```
class ColorPoint extends Point{
    var color;
}
```

How can the ColorPoint subclass know at runtime the position of x and y?
This is a static information so I guess that I would need to provide a header like file where the compiler that will compile the ColorPoint class can lookup the Point class and statically knows the relative positions of the various properties.

I guess there should be a much better way.
Should I also save property names inside the class_t struct?

Comment: And what happens when you change the definition of `Point` to add a new field? How will the compiler know to recompile all derived classes?

Comment: Over the years, there have been many attempts to optimize property (and method) lookup in dynamic languages such as Smalltalk, Self and Objective-C. Searching around the internet will find you many papers describing different algorithms. Here is just one, which I happen to have handy, but don't regard it is as "the best"; it's just a starting point: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.121.1786